# How to check and return a couple of values through a recursive function?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I want to check if a number in the first array is equal any number in the second array and return the values of the indices using a recursive algorithm.

```
public class RecursionAlgorithms1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1 = {7,1,5,10,8,4,15,60};
        int [] array2 = {1,10,8,5,15,7,60,4};
        int result[] = Check(array1, array2);
        //for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(result[7]);
        //}
    }

    public static int[] Check(int [] arr1,int [] arr2){
        int index1=8;
        int index2=8;
        if (arr1[index1] != arr2[index2]) {
            return Check(arr1, arr2);
        }
        else{
            return new int [] {index1,index2};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PradeepSimha if someone can Code it C# and I Change it to Java .. its OK

Comment: Is use of recursion is required? Generally it's a good practice to remove recursion, and write it in iterative way.

Comment: It is fine to use recursion in some cases, where it makes the code simpler and cleaner, but this does not seem to be one of those cases.

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko yes it is Required , it is so easy by using Iterations :D ... but it is Required :S

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes it is Really easy and simpler and Cleaner but we are forced to use Recursion :D :S

Comment: One tip - you need to add parameters to allow the problem to be split into smaller sub-problems.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan it is just an idea its implementation is hard :S
can u write its Code ?

Comment: Yes, I can write the code. I'm not going to post it because the only point I can see to doing this recursively is for you to learn to write recursive code. Start by thinking about how to split a problem into two or more subproblems, each smaller than the original problem.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Okay :D .. can you give me Hints to solve this :D

Comment: Yes, I just gave you the first important hint. The essence of recursion is splitting all except the smallest problems into two or more subproblems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write it like this:

```
public class Arrays1 {
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1 = {7,10,5,100,80,40,15,60};
        int [] array2 = {10,100,80,5,15,7,60,40};
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                   System.out.println("(" + i + "," + j + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey it is Easy To do it with this ! .. I need it with FunctionS

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not implemented properly. At each recursive call, indexes of arrays should be modfied, otherwise it will keep on comparing same elements from two arrays.

Comment: Sure I still Don't have a Strategy to return the Values

Comment: about the modification of indices It will be Solved but First
do you have any strategy to Return them Using Recursion inside the If Statements ?

Comment: put two base conditions. either elements found equal or both array reached their ends then return appropriately...

Comment: There is an Error if I put the return Function inside the if Statement :S

Comment: now in my Code it is OK but have another Errors !


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at recursionalgorithms1.RecursionAlgorithms1.Check(RecursionAlgorithms1.java:30)
 at recursionalgorithms1.RecursionAlgorithms1.main(RecursionAlgorithms1.java:20)
Java Result: 1

I want to know how to fix what I did ... any Ideas !

Comment: You seem to have a fine strategy to return the values - use a two element int[]. I suggest returning null if there is no match.

Comment: How Can I return null ! ... I need to Check them again by using the same Function ... if i returned null so it is not used by recursion :S

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not required. This will find common element in both arrays

```
int [] array1 = {7,1,5,10,8,4,15,60};
int [] array2 = {1,10,8,5,15,7,60,4};
Integer[] arr=new Integer[array2.length];
for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
    arr[i]=array2[i];
}


for(int i:array1){
   if(Arrays.asList(arr).contains(i)){
       System.out.println("Both arrays have "+i);
   }
}
```

Out put.

```
Both arrays have 7
Both arrays have 1
Both arrays have 5
Both arrays have 10
Both arrays have 8
Both arrays have 4
Both arrays have 15
Both arrays have 60
```

Comment: can u write the same Code Using Recursion ? 
I mean to make a Function and Recall it again inside itself
and output the Indices that have the same Number and put them in pairs.
and get the Output like This : Those are the Indices of the Arrays Which Contain the Same Number from Array 1 and Array 2. 
(0,5),(1,0),(2,3),(3,1),(4,2),(5,7),(6,4),(7,6)

Comment: @user3095127 you can try that. Come here with what you tried.